# Prestashop - Price Drop Category

Tags: php, prestashop, categories

I'm building shop with PrestaShop, my client wants to have buttons that lead to price-drop site with products from certain category.

I made override, links lead to /prices-drop?mod_category=4, everything works fine BUT ps_categorytree doesnt seem to know in which category you actualy are right now,

For example: I click on button to lead to prices-drop with category men, it shows products from this category with price drop so everything with that is fine, but module ps_categorytree shows last category you were in on website, not category from link,

Anyone have idea how I can "tell" ps_categorytree what category products are?

Comment: If you can add more detail with snap shot.